# Hive not inserting data into table from select on ORC to ORC

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, orc

I'm running a query that selects data from a table, inserting it into another table
Both the tables are stored on AWS in ORC data file formats

Scenario 1: **NOT WORKING**
`create table abc.target as select * from abc.source`
Not all records are being inserted

`select * from abc.source where customer_id in ('1', '2', '3')`
When I do only a select with where condition, I'm able to see filtered data
But when I insert (all records - without where condition), only partial data (customer id's other than 1,2,3)is inserted in the target table but I can't see the records that I need  (customer id's - 1,2,3)

Scenario 2: **WORKING**
`create table abc.target as select * from abc.source where customer_id in ('1', '2', '3')`
When I insert only a few records(the ones I filtered in the select statement), data is getting inserted into target

Used hive settings:

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions = 5000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode = 1000;
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=TRUE; 
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive=TRUE;
```

I also tried : creating a table before hand with correct data types and INSERT INTO / INSERT OVERWRITE
but that too didn't work

**Not able to figure out why it works with filtered records and doesn't work when I insert all, any suggestions, clues are highly appreciated**

Comment: do you have too much data ? like in 100s of million? sometime it can take time to process data and give it like 1/2hrs to load all data.